# What temperature is my stove?

Tags: code-golf

My stovetop has 10 (0 through 9) different settings of heat and a very odd way of cycling through them.

- It always starts at 0
- When I hit plus it increments the number, *unless* the number is 9 in which case it becomes 0, or the number is 0 in which case it becomes 9.
- When I hit minus it decrements the number, *unless* the number is zero in which case it becomes 4.

There are no other temperature control buttons.

In this challenge you will take as input a string of commands and output which setting my stovetop ends up on after running that sequence.

Answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Input

You may take input in any of the following formats:

- A list/array/vector/stream of booleans/1s or 0s/1s or -1s
- A string (or list/array/vector/stream) of two different characters (which should be consistent for your program)

And you may output

- An integer on the range 0-9.
- A character on the range '0'-'9'.
- A string of size 1 consisting of the above.

### Testcases

Input as a string `-` for decrement and `+` for increment.

```
 : 0
- : 4
+ : 9
-- : 3
-+ : 5
+- : 8
++ : 0
--- : 2
--+ : 4
-+- : 4
-++ : 6
+-- : 7
+-+ : 9
++- : 4
+++ : 9
---- : 1
---+ : 3
```

Comment: May a string list of input be newline separated?

Comment: @DomHastings I think that that is a standard way to take a list of strings in.

Comment: (I see that this is a relatively weird input format) Can I take input like this `f(f(f(0,M),M),P)`? (for the string `MMP`) What about `(M)(M)(P)`?

Comment: @user202729 No.

Comment: (for reference, boost preprocessor library takes sequence input in the second form above.)

Comment: @user202729 If it is a standard way of taking input you don't need to ask.  If it is not then either it should be, in which case you should bring that up in the relevant place on meta, or it shouldn't be in which case I don't intend to permit it.

Comment: Does this structure correspond to some well known mathematical object or group?

Comment: @Jonah Under the equivalence by temperature (`+` = `+++` because they both give 9), they certainly don't form a group. Something like 5+9 is not well defined (9 can be represented by any odd number of `+`s so 5+9 could be 6, 8 or 0). Under the equivalence of the sequences themselves, they also don't form a group. They are isomorphic binary strings under concatenation and thus don't have an inverse.  You can relax the latter into a category, and try some other stuff but nothing really interesting come out of it. I don't think this corresponds to any mathematical structure of any note.

Comment: A related question could be "Take as input the initial temperature and the final temperature and output the necessary increment/decrement sequence."

Comment: @LorenDB I think that is kind of interesting.  I wonder what portion of the pairs require doing anything interesting as opposed to just incrementing or decrementing to get the desired number.

Comment: @Wheat Wizard good point. Most cases with the stove starting at 0 would be interesting.

Comment: “Inverse” challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/242543/75323 (cc @LorenDB)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>38 37</s>  36 bytes

Expects an array of Boolean values, with *false* for `+` and *true* for `-`. Returns an integer.

```javascript
a=>a.map(c=>a=a++?c?a-2:a%10:9>>c)|a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7LDoIwEAXQPV8xITHQTFpUfEFS/BDjYlLBaBCIJa78d@Th1KhdNad35vZKD7LmfmlaWdWnvCt0RzojdaMmNP1FE@Le7EkuU5ot5mmSZUY8qWtz24IGCzoDU1e2LnNV1uewCA9KKXucFoyvoDUEMhBCeN4wFvo@9EdAFMH8LdJnWb0FnSScGUKjxCzIsuYpl9mxuIzrGhaNsnSC/ne7RPknnNm4Ls5snXAmce2/exB/M3L40CiLj@AkcfcC)

#### Commented

It's important to note that `a++` with `a = [ true ]` is evaluated to `NaN` because it's first coerced to the string `"true"` and then to a number. That's why we can safely re-use the array `a[]` to store the temperature even when we get the singleton `[ true ]` as input.

```javascript
a =>             // a[] = input array, re-used to store the temperature
  a.map(c =>     // for each command c in a[]:
    a =          //   update the temperature:
      a++ ?      //     if a is numeric and not equal to 0
                 //     (increment it afterwards):
        c ?      //       if this is a '-':
          a - 2  //         subtract 2
        :        //       else:
          a % 10 //         apply a modulo 10
      :          //     else:
        9 >> c   //       yield 4 if this is a '-', or 9 if this is a '+'
  ) | a          // end of map(); return the final result
```

Answer (score 8):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>103</s> <s>90</s> <s>86</s> <s>75</s> 71 bytes

```php
while($k=$argv[1][$i++])--$k?$p?$p++<9?:$p=0:$p=9:($p--?:$p=4);echo+$p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VLJtVRKL0suiDWOjVTK1tWM1dXVVsu1VCoBIW9vG0t5KpcDWAERYWmmoFOjqggVMNK1TkzPytVUKrP///28EAA) - Add string as argument - 1 for `-`, 2 for `+`. Example: for `---+`, `1112`.

Thanks to @Kaddath for -13 bytes (see comment). -4 by changing input format to 0/1. -11 thanks to @640KB. -4 thanks to @DewiMorgan.

Comment: [-13 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYlLCoQwEAUv02Ca0KDgwn8OMogEUSMKPhJxM8zZM2ZRBUXBIXYGr9fLL3Z2Ktx@Cjj3W5H12/MpRraBDv7S0WWSGUVIDJUh9HlD0Jpf9zU3aRFEUpbc/pbZXYQ2xiii/w) with some further golf: no need to init `$p`, used `$k<'-'` instead of `$k=='+'` (compared by ascii order), replaced `$p==0` by `$p` with ternary alternatives the other way round, and replaced `$p==9` by `$p>8`. Also you don't need the curly braces for the `foreach` (only one instruction)

Comment: You can [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYhLCoAgFAAv8xY@QjBoUfbxIBEhYhkFPVTaRGc3XczADDlKg6Ls7fZWG8dC9Gug64gMtN@fuV5QBzjxhVMxoMLUKqBRSKCqwuyxQ5k356pEg/1njbuB@pSSEOIH) by merging the decrement on the ternary (`$p?$p--:$p=4`) => (`$p--?:$p=4`).

Comment: Only issue is that it seems to fail on the [empty string case](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzSKS4riiwtyMks0VBKL0suiDWM1E4tVsjWrVbLtNVQKQNjOwl6lwNbASqVAW1sTSNpaalqBpFQKdHVBXBNN69rU5Ix8lQLr////AwA) - returns `4` instead of `0`.

Comment: @640KB Oh well, thanks for trying! If you can figure out a way to fix the empty string case, give me that version.

Comment: if you're good with using `a` for `-` and `b` for `+` (or any alpha chars really), you can do this: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VLJtVRKL0suiDWOjDWpUMrW1YzWBYrZJ9ioFQKStbWNpb6VSYGsAIiytNFQKdHXBAiaa1qnJGfkqBTUG1v///08CAA). Ironically, I think it was the changing to `0` and `1` that bit you on the empty string case since in PHP `''` string and `'0'` char both evaluate to `falsey`. I beat up the ternary a bit more too... it promises to behave better now. There's probably more air to let out on it but I'll leave the rest to you!

Comment: Oh and sadly the `STDIN` trick won't work since you can't take a null or empty input that way...

Comment: I don't understand the `0|` and the `|0` - both seem redundant, and removing them saves 4 bytes without apparently changing the output (other than adding a warning).

Comment: @DewiMorgan You're right that the first can be removed, but the second is necessary for the empty string case

Comment: Oh, good call, I didn't try that! In that case, instead of `echo$p|0`, try `echo+$p`. Seems to work, and gives you another -1 :)

Comment: Ooh, try 1 and 2 instead of a and b. Then `$k==b?` can become `--$k?`. Another -1. It ain't much, but it's honest work :D

Answer (score 7):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>58</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>56</s></sup> 54 bytes

```c
t;f(*s){for(t=0;*s;)t=*s++-7?t?t-1:4:t?-~t%10:9;*s=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwELznK1ZISAZsFfJoGhw3h6pf0eRAiUlQUxJhV0WN6KeX@gWlscAsOzO743VO8lNWHbpO0gKFIrgW5xpJFtNQ0ECyUEQRWW7kRpIknadyQ76ln8TpSuFM0rYrKwnvWVmhYHKdgFr5MatDkFxI8bIDBlfPw@ARvUUmMiExcWTTLm8Bi5DI0RzPEp2ql/U6J1RoS40HbYo3F55LvrcmYgxzDCsMMwwLDA8YVGZqkuq5x7A0qOUkiuYq2dPkR56/8dqdZ9s8T7fN6km9C9159D/rHagpAtI2ymrPGyWLqQvXIMovfi5QbzC4c4lwyFCIIsMOwA51NFhVyw7XEHZ0wHW3E68ULmStAiSD/@DrR1G8aEYEyUj3Z9XZhDXThYyJYKDpZSqUegrSfBjMZ7CBJaQmMaqJNPWmv1C63sONb66g4cJuD3apFaVAni@APIK/B19sKzV4iUHg4W4EY3znOraTtvvJi1N2EB35/AU)

*Saved <s>a</s> 3 bytes thanks to [Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/johan-du-toit)!!!*

Inputs a string of minuses and <s>pluses</s> bell-characters (ASCII 7) and returns the stovetop temperature in the input string (right at the end where the `'\0'` terminator would have been).

Comment: You could save one  character by using a one-digit encoded character instead of '+', but it's just one byte. Upvoted.

Comment: @Davide I just did that 2 minutes ago! T_T But my comment was backwards - fixed! :)

Comment: Ahaha I swear that I didn't see it! I was busy modifying the TIO to see if you could use an array of int instead.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##XVHbToNAEH3vV0xISFjYjfRmLduVB@NX2D5Uulii0oYdE2KDv457A1s3XIY5Z2bOHAr2VhR9j7yMqhpjRS7lqYlQpDxWnKCIVZKwVY45smm2yDBnPxhO02zNUSDvel0En/uqjsjkMgF9iuO@iQGlQvWyAwGXIKAQMPNIbGRDZuPEpX3eAQ5hiad5niP6qqFsqPOFGu241WBEyfYsC5QHJyKlsKCwpjCnsKTwQEFnZjapr3sKK4s6zlTTfCe3TXGUxbts/D7b9nm2bddP@l6ayVff80GBNhGMoVrKQba6LOU@3ICqvuWpjAaB5M4n4jHDIUksm4Az9cpY3cuZawk7PuJm2utXWb4obD5kHSG5Av/0eC2wETAS7Twyks2xnSqzMNqXgMUcclhBZhO3Y5WmlZEpIbeA1MD4I/4LPjeaUkZBqIA9QniAUG1rbShSUHT0XAkhd75tN@n6Xw)

Comment: @JohanduToit Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: cool, with clang you could have used `f(*s){...` but the return value trick doesn't work.

Comment: @JohanduToit Yeah, it's a trade-off which one saves more bytes.

Comment: This may be valid depending on how you interpret the specifications [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVHZboMwEHzPV6yQkGxsqzmbBofyUPUrkjykxDSoKYlsV0KN6K9TX5C0FscyO7s7OxSsOO3r907yrkSJwtfyLBFPFMcySxQhbJnLXLJJOk9lzn5kPBmnK952Va3hc1/VCI@uIzCnOO5lAloorTY7yOAaRRQiZh/ERS5kLiYeDrhP@AwjgRZ4nhiq@rK@LhSabMudBitKNBdRaHHwIsYU5hRWFGYUFhSeKBhk6kBzPVJYuqznTAwtdPLbFEdRfAgZ9tk2r9Nts3ox98JOvvue9QqMe4CsjKo@iMaUjXkI16Cqb3EuUS8QPwQgGRAOhDg2Bm/qnbGmlzfXEXZ8yNtpb19luVFankSNNL5L3vQELbDOYCC6eXgg2@M6VXZh7V4ZzGeQwxJSB9w6S9fwNgjZSvxXljCc4X/8132RhlKiKFbAniE@QKy2tfFVU5B0sF5mmdiFtu2o7X4B)

Comment: @JohanduToit The function needs to be self-contained, you can't declared variables used in the function outside of the byte count. And you can't return through a global.

Comment: how about this: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwELznK1ZISAZsFfJoGhw3h6pf0eRAiUlQUxJhV0WN6KeX@gWlscAsOzO743VO8lNWHbpO0gKFIrgW5xpJFtNQ0ECyUEQRWW7kRpIknadyQ76ln8TpSuFM0rYrKwnvWVmhYHKdgFr5MatDkFxI8bIDBlfPw@ARvUUmMiExcWTTLm8Bi5DI0RzPEp2ql/U6J1RoS40HbYo3F55LvrcmYgxzDCsMMwwLDA8YVGZqkuq5x7A0qOUkiuYq2dPkR56/8dqdZ9s8T7fN6km9C9159D/rHagpAtI2ymrPGyWLqQvXIMovfi5QbzC4c4lwyFCIIsMOwA51NFhVyw7XEHZ0wHW3E68ULmStAiSD/@DrR1G8aEYEyUj3Z9XZhDXThYyJYKDpZSqUegrSfBjMZ7CBJaQmMaqJNPWmv1C63sONb66g4cJuD3apFaVAni@APIK/B19sKzV4iUHg4W4EY3znOraTtvvJi1N2EB35/AU) ; )

Comment: @JohanduToit Perfect! Very nicely done - thanks! :D

Comment: cool! I think in your description you may want to call it a null-terminated array of integers instead of a string.

Comment: @JohanduToit It's a wide-character string, which is **both** a string and a null-terminated array of integers! :P

Comment: true. This does not save any bytes but removes the need to change the `+` to a bell. [TIO](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwELznK1ZISAZsFfJomzg0h6pfkeRAiUlQUxJhV40a0U8vXT@gNBaYZWd2dzzOWX7Mqn3bKl6QUAbX4lQTlcY8lDxQaSijyJ@t1Ip9Kz@JF/OFWimWLKaIp4o3bVkpeM/KigSj6whw5YesDkEJqeR6CylcPY@Cx/QWmciEzMSRTbu8BSzCIkdzPEt0VV1ZV@cKEW240aBFictZ5ErsrIiYwpTCnMKEwozCIwXMjE0Sn3sKDwa1nARprpM9TX4Q@Zuo3Xk2l5fx5jJ/xnemJw/@J50CdBGIllFWO3HBspi7cAmy/BKngnQCgzuXCPsMhygy7ACsqQNjsZc11xC2vMf1tKOoEJeqxoCo4D/4@lEUa82IIBnU/Ul1MmGZ6kZGRNDT9DIdSu2Cws@gBdHIzTiJtG7kjUyBUH8/t@c410gpiOdLYE/g78CXmwp9VhQk7a9CpqnYuonNqGl/8uKY7WXLPn8B)

Comment: I did not know that you can dynamically allocate arrays like this is c: `int buf[strlen(s)];` MSVC does not like it at all :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```rust
|x|x.fold(0,|u,v|if u>0{u-v*2+1}else{9>>v}%10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3vCoIwFMW/@xQ3Idhq1db/CHyRiBC7kmAmcxPD@ew2jcr1aef87tk5UheqjTO4h0lGaO2dSoxGpzOD/uUfIb6E8Z/8UvGjoqPeJztMD/JWOj1O07DL2XBX/nbcpe7feZ4olITO72FOTGUqxz@NmD3p27T9NX6kV8KZ0aw0SQw64LWelZPlVDSYFlgfgqBsxoLTltqsvGAY3breXCaZGhG/bsBnFaVH6EmaWeZxWMMBVrCBPXBYWreGLews67iAlW/ziwVglWOk8AoSC50qr2lf)

Takes an `Iterator` of zeros (for `+`) and ones (for `-`), and returns the resulting stove temperature. Taking -1s and 1s doesn't seem to help, because `(-1,1) -> (4,9)` isn't trivial to represent in integer arithmetic.

Uses [Arnauld's input method and bit-shift trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218367/78410) for the zero case. Also, Rust's if-else expression can be a part of larger expression, so `%10` is factored out to avoid the parentheses in `(u-v*2+1)%10`.

Answer (score 6):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 41 bytes

Takes in a list of 0 for + and 1 for -.

```
  }{
0>?@`"+1
^ 1-0=v
`15|8*v
|<<,<+<
^10
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiICB9e1xuMD4/QGBcIisxXG5eIDEtMD12XG5gMTV8OCp2XG58PDwsPCs8XG5eMTAiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMSAxIDAifQ==)

[image: stove]

`a` loops around and based on the input `}` goes `@` down towards `-1` and mod 15 `|15` (to set -1 to 14), or goes to `+1` and `+ ((a=0) * 8)` – thus gets set to 9 if `n` was 0. We join both paths `,` and with mod 10 `|10` we get 14 -> 4, 10 -> 0. If the input is empty, `a` goes on `?` to the side path to the output `}`.

(The `^` next to the 10 shouldn't be necessary, but I haven't fixed the bug yet.)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Input as a list of `-1`/`1` for `-`/`+` respectively.

```
ÎvD_Ƶ≠yè*yOθ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cF@ZS/yxrY86F1QeXqFV6X9ux///0YY6uoY6hrEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waf@oYZ6udmXK4RVeSgoah/drKjxqm6SgZP/foLLMJf7Y1kedCyoPr9Cq9D@343@tjmbM/@joWJ1oXUMgYQhm6OhCabAQhAfhgOXg0rpwQSQtcE0wfXBzECahmIVsHFhtLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Î             # Push 0 and the input-list
 v            # Loop `y` over the input-list:
  D           #  Duplicate the current value
   _          #  Pop the copy, and check that it's 0 (1 if 0; 0 otherwise)
    Ƶ≠        #  Push compressed integer 185
      yè      #  Index `y` into it (0-based modulair, so the leading 1 is ignored, while
              #  1→8 and -1→5)
        *     #  Multiply it to the ==0 boolean
         y    #  Push `y`
          O   #  Take the sum of the three values on the stack
           θ  #  And only leave the last digit (for 10→0)
              # (after the loop, the value is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶ≠` is `185`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 39 bytes

Takes input as a list of `1/-1`

```
reduce$((p,k)->[k%7-2,p+k][p>0]%10,?,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LbsIwEEX3/opZgGxrbBQehRaJ9Ce6oyxCcFQrIVh@qAvKt6eehHYzd@7MmTv1rb71KQ7N4XPw5pJqMxPCqVbq8tjOd3qlHLanoyuL03xZqHdVyOH7y3YGPnwyewZQKTjDAWzvUhQSfkpYBNfZKDjsgctMeBNSFzNT0fZauRlwQL5obH@hSWdDJG0oLQTj4/8J5UZxphTnqW34vXqALuE@IQ8uh/ynYDrXDcNc35gms2aa3AtDcq8MceLG5Sorjhca9VPJbzNNfpd1ysLnHvEvewSW1NBk/Qs)

This uses `((-1)%7-2)%10 = (6-2)%10 = 4` and `(1%7-2)%10 = (-1)%10 = 9`, which works because in Python the result of the modulo operation has the same sign as the divisor.
`-k%-7` would work instead of `k%7-2` and is one byte shorter if we swap `-1` and `1` in the input, but that feels like abusing the input format.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 33 bytes

```
^
0
{T`+09d`_9d`^.\+
T`-d`_4d`^.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP47LgKs6JEHbwDIlIR6I4/RitLlCEnSBPBMQT/f/fwUrBQMuXSBpwqUNJC25dEEcYy5dEM@USxvEs@DS1oaoA0saAWltsA5dbV0oDeKbAVWD@OZAGmKWNlReWxtmNliBIYgBEjEGAA) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
^
0
```

Start with heat setting 0.

```
{
```

Process all of the control buttons.

```
T`+09d`_9d`^.\+
```

If the control button is a plus, then delete it (by transliterating to `_`) and cyclically increment the digit (`` T`9d`d `` is the standard way to cyclically increment digits) but change `0` to `9` instead by listing it as an exception before the expansion of `d` to `0123456789`.

```
T`-d`_4d`^.-
```

If the control button is a minus, then delete it and decrement the digit, but use `4` instead of the usual `9` for cyclic decrement.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```hs
0#1=9
0#a=4
9#1=0
x#a=x+a
f=foldl(#)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30DZ0NaSy0A50daEyxLINuCqALIrtBO50mzT8nNScjSUNQ3@5yZm5tkWFGXmlaikRRvqKACRLhQbxv4HAA)

- Saved 8 thanks to @Wheat Wizard

Comment: [35](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30DZ0NaSy0A50daEyxLINuCqALIrtBO50mzT8nNScjSUNQ3@5yZm5tkWFGXmlaikRRvqKACRLhQbxv4HAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: And if you want to keep the same input format [39](https://tio.run/##VY3LDoIwEEX3/YqLKxpqbH3XWL9AVy4NMSRKNCASH5GF/46dghabppkz507nlNyzY57XtQykGTMZKKOZtq9kRZCZIsqirK9YatJrfsjDgMv6kpwLg0tSbvYon4/t47YusGO4n64vVIgi9GBW9rEV9UKkts3BGjXAsSoXXhPijbCCoJJj2affEO5i0BGQXDiWccPjllXL@usFJQRGP1aOJ9986@c/brz08zYhMOywiv0@S853mfzU/@/8rMPktd/3N6/aed3d7xLqr0OZEUfM6KL@AA "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

Takes `-1` for `-` and `1` for `+`.

```
0(10|15|++8*0=<.)/@|.@,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xDsIwDEX3nMJicYvrkACFEqiEhMTExIo6IVpg4QIVVw@taJwhQwY/fb/vvP1MYwu1A4QCDLjhsYbT9XL2JrOmt2VPVM1NfdD54tjrY9H4XKluXLm5Fix/ARkIX7pR6nF/fiDbd/nAmAknMjgddIAI/3k9zRzAbgIUwCokJFIGIpkqLEkm9JBkluLhpDyaBEXVRpCkttKX3p26iNJUdNl4F6d/Hm3@Bw)

```
0(10|15|++8*0=<.)/@|.@,]
0                    @,] prepend a 0 and …
                  @|.    rotate and …
 (              )/       fold from the left:
            0=<.         if the minimum of the step and the accumulator is 0
                           (can only happen if they are 1/0)
         +8*             add 8 to …
        +                the sum of the step and the accumulator
     15|                 mod 15 to get -1 -> 14
  10|                    mod 10 to get 10 -> 0, and 14 -> 4
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
n=0
for b in input():n=[b%7-2,n+b][n>0]%10
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/z9aAKy2/SCFJITMPiApKSzQ0rfJso5NUzXWNdPK0k2Kj8@wMYlUNDbgKijLzShTy/gO1cZVnZOakKhhapVakJiuADPsfHcsVrWsIJAzBDB0FXRgDLAjlQ7kQeSQ1ukgSKHqRtCOMQDIV2WB0s9HMh@gCAA)

Takes input as ±1's. Pretty explicitly fixes the `n=0` case to have `b=-1` give `4` and `b=1` give `9`. There's probably a better way.

**50 bytes**

```python
n=0
for b in input():n=((n or 9-b%5)+b)%10
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/z9aAKy2/SCFJITMPiApKSzQ0rfJsNTTyFICilrpJqqaa2kmaqoYGXAVFmXklCnn/gdq4yjMyc1IVDK1SK1KTFUCG/Y@O5YrWNQQShmCGjoIujAEWhPKhXIg8khpdJAkUvUjaEUYgmYpsMLrZaOZDdAEA)

Answer (score 4):

### [R](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPp-ngrtDuAhUwy4UKHXuIDPQQFjAAegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw0pGNScRjIdSkNXK6Ky1j_m), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
f=function(x){for(i in x)F=(F+i)%%10+"if"(i>0,8,-5)*!F;F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM6Lb9II1MhM0@hQtPNVsNNO1NTVdXQQFspM01JI9POQMdCR9dUU0vRzdqt9n@aRnFibkFOqkayhq6hjqGmjqGBqZlOUWqBbUhQqKumJleaBpCjYahjAWeD1EF4yRogLZr/AQ)

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM6Lb9II1MhM0@hQtPNVsNNO1NTVdXQQDshMy1BI9POQMdCR9dUU0vRzdqt9n@aRnFibkFOqkayhq6hjqGmjqGBqZlOUWqBbUhQqKumJleaBpCjYahjAWeD1BmAeckaIC2a/wE) by using ```"if"``` instead of ```ifelse```...

Comment: Yes, I read about this trick only yesterday and should revisit my solutions accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <sup><s>47</s></sup> 43 bytes

Expects each operation on a separate line with `+` for increment and `-` for decrement

```
/-/{a?a--:a=4}/+/{a=a?++a%10:9}END{print+a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fX1e/OtE@UVfXKtHWpFZfG8izTbTX1k5UNTSwsqx19XOpLijKzCvRTqz9/1@XSxsBAQ)

Answer (score 3):

### x86-16 machine code, 40 bytes

Port of @Arnauld's answer. Be sure to upvote him! (Example run is unneccecary since it's just a port.)

```
0BAC:0100  31 DB E3 23 AC 84 DB 74-14 84 C0 75 04 FE CB EB   1..#...t...u....
0BAC:0110  14 FE C3 89 D8 B7 0A F6-F7 88 C3 EB 08 B3 09 86   ................
0BAC:0120  C8 D2 EB 86 C8 E2 DD C3                           ........
```

Callable function.

Expects `[SI]` = index of list (0x00 for `-`, 0x01 for `+`), `CX` = length of list.

Needs a spare `AX`.

Function output is to `BL` (accumulator value).

Disassembled:

```
0BAC:0100 31DB          XOR     BX,BX
0BAC:0102 E323          JCXZ    0127
0BAC:0104 AC            LODSB
0BAC:0105 84DB          TEST    BL,BL
0BAC:0107 7414          JZ      011D
0BAC:0109 84C0          TEST    AL,AL
0BAC:010B 7504          JNZ     0111
0BAC:010D FECB          DEC     BL
0BAC:010F EB14          JMP     0125
0BAC:0111 FEC3          INC     BL
0BAC:0113 89D8          MOV     AX,BX
0BAC:0115 B70A          MOV     BH,0A
0BAC:0117 F6F7          DIV     BH
0BAC:0119 88C3          MOV     BL,AL
0BAC:011B EB08          JMP     0125
0BAC:011D B309          MOV     BL,09
0BAC:011F 86C8          XCHG    CL,AL
0BAC:0121 D2EB          SHR     BL,CL
0BAC:0123 86C8          XCHG    CL,AL
0BAC:0125 E2DD          LOOP    0104
0BAC:0127 C3            RET
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pF`, 36 bytes

```perl
$\+=$\?1-2*/-/:9-5*/-/,$\%=10for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJcbeUNdIS19X38pS1xRE66jEqNoaGqTlFzm41Vb//6@trf0vv6AkMz@v@L9ugRsA)

Comment: Nice solution! As the input format can be newline separated, you could save 5 bytes just omitting the `for@F` part ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJcbeUNdIS19X38pS1xRE66jEqNoaGtRW//@vzaXLpf0vv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")), also with a bit of fudge in the `-F` you can save another two, replacing `5*/-/` with `$#F`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWJcbeUNdIS19X38pSV0XZzVolRtXW0KC2@v9/bS5dLu1/@QUlmfl5xf91C3Lc9DVAQFcTBPQB "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>27</del> 26 bytes

```
00000000: 33c0 803c 2d74 0a84 c075 02b0 0840 37eb  3..<-t...u...@7.
00000010: 0548 3f14 003f 46e2 e9c3                 .H?..?F...
```

**Listing:**

```
33 C0           XOR  AX, AX             ; clear accumulator 
            SLOOP: 
80 3C 2D        CMP  BYTE PTR[SI], '-'  ; is a "-"? 
74 0A           JZ   MINUS              ; is a minus operation 
84 C0           TEST AL, AL             ; is plus op and 0? 
75 02           JNZ  PLUS               ; if not, continue as plus op 
B0 08           MOV  AL, 8              ; otherwise add 8 
            PLUS:
40              INC  AX                 ; increment 
37              AAA                     ; if al > 9 { al = 0, cf = 1 } 
EB 06           JMP  DONE               ; done 
            MINUS: 
48              DEC  AX                 ; decrement 
3F              AAS                     ; if al < 0 { al = 9, cf = 1 } 
14 00           ADC  AL, 0              ; if cf { al = 10 }
3F              AAS                     ; if al == 10 { al = 4 } 
            DONE:
46              INC  SI                 ; next input instruction 
E2 E8           LOOP SLOOP
C3              RET                     ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input as string in `[SI]`, length in `CX`.  Output to `AL`.

This is the first time I can ever think of where [`AAA`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aaa) and [`AAS`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aas) were actually useful in a challenge! These instructions, intended for BCD math, are able to be abused a little to do a bit of the dirty work here.

**Tests:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 92 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,t=0:f(x[1:],{"+":{9:0,0:9},"-":{0:4}}[x[0]].get(t,t+eval(f"{x[0]}1")))if x else t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8DWgCstv0ghWyEzD4gKSks0NK24FBQy0xSybW3VtdVBHDC3wNbWwKrA1hLMT82BiFhagQyAiBSnWhVo2xpyIas24YLJ6AJlCooy80o0CjT//9cFgv8A)

Expects input as a string of "-" and "+" as in the test cases.
Recursively looks up the few exceptions or defaults to adding and subtracting one based on the first character of the given string.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) to see if there's any way you can shorten your answer.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```
Prompt A
For(I,1,dim(ʟA
If ʟA(I:Then
Ans+1+8not(Ans
Ans(Ans≤9
Else
Ans-1+5not(Ans
End
End
```

-5 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Takes input as a list of 0s and 1s. Output is stored in `Ans` as an integer. Note that there can not be empty lists in TI-Basic, so the first test case throws an error. The below version has 8 bytes more but outputs 0 for the first test case.

---

#### <s>60</s> 55 bytes

```
Prompt Str1
For(I,1,length(Str1
If expr(sub(Str1,I,1:Then
Ans+1+8not(Ans
Ans(Ans≤9
Else
Ans-1+5not(Ans
End
End
```

Takes input as a string of "0"s and "1"s. Output is stored in `Ans` as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>151</del> 117 bytes

```python
p=0
for k in input():
  if k=='+':
    if p==0:p=9
    elif p==9:p=0
    else:p+=1
  if p==0:p=4
  else:p-=1
print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8DWgCstv0ghWyEzD4gKSks0NK24FBQy0xSybW3VtdVBHDC3wNbWwKrA1hLMT82BiFhagQyAiBSnWhVo2xpyIas24YLJ6AJlCooy80o0CjT//9cFgv8A)

@pxeger So Nice thank you -35 bytes

Comment: [You can put the body of the if statements on the same lines](https://pxeger.net/92116a); then [you can swap the `'+'` and the `k` which allows you to remove the space after `if`](https://pxeger.net/92116b); then [you can indent with only one space](https://pxeger.net/92116c); we normally count imports, so you'd have to add 20 for `from sys import argv` but [you can just use `input()`](https://pxeger.net/92116d). Check out [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54) for more advice

Comment: If you are going to continue to use `argv` as your input method, `from sys import *` is a shorter import, or just `import sys` and qualifying the one use of `argv` is even shorter.

Comment: [75](https://tio.run/##LY09D4MgEIZ3fgVxASIkmnZoiXaza5duxqGxNBobjyCm@uspHyZH7r2H50DvdoD55Hp4q5oQ4qAu0AcMnvA4@9KrpUxCTSmIkp9ZC1XZcT/lJS/8dLt0/Jooa6eKCNIhbcbZUmDOv4es2SXC@DeMX4WfZlUSq031NHzIkNp6pS1uHvfGGDAS69eyuCxDmfAnDz0EEVIeUWIRRiryJCQjKsk@9MNPC/7mDw "Python 3 – Try It Online") by using nested tuple indexing instead of `if` statements. You could also lose the brackets in the `print` by switching to Python 2.

Comment: @ElPedro why have you put all the inputs in quotes? That would only be necessary with Python 2 without `raw_input`, probably wouldn't be an accepted IO method, and in Python 3 gives wrong outputs

Comment: @pxeger [Thanks - corrected.](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoIwEIb3e4rb2qZtAtFBG3DD1cWNMBiskWC4ppQIT19bTG74v@@/3LktvGk6xJ6etmaMRaoLeJHHEYcpjVsCF4ZqzkmX6ihaqspOJZKlKhJdTp06/61ox4pp1oHzwxQ4iZjuQfCbAcTve/hYvPvFGrSr7Xl@KMCuvXUBm9u18Z68QfeY5wgaJGgNWoJMMecEibTMMtukc7vXe58XtPwB "Python 3 – Try It Online") It was simply because I originally wrote it in Python 2 to avoid the brackets in the `print` then changed it to Python 3 as that was what OP had used and forgot to remove the quotes! :-)

Comment: My god -35 bytes @pxeger

Comment: @ElPedro you are talented, post seperate answer, because it will be a copy

Comment: @WasifHasan - Feel free to post it as an update to your answer. It's just a copy of your algorithm using different techniques. Would suggest you leave your current answer there as well as it makes your approach easier to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 132 bytes

```
([](<()>)){({}[()]<((){[()](<(({}({})[()]{})[(()()()()()){}])((){[()](<{}>)}{}){((<{}{}>))}{}>)}{}){(<{}(((({})()){}){}{})>)}{}>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxCoAwDEWv8/9W99KLlA7VRREcuoacPSaKlgSS/3jJOvpx7X07zVAbMlhIgWgFWwYosTh35M1IzwC/omjjNEUL1RVB7JGokzkC4tl7yDBYfsPMFkuWbg)

This loses a lot of bytes to simple equality checks (equals 0 and equals 10).

Answer (score 2):

### [CESIL](http://www.obelisk.me.uk/cesil/) , 850 bytes (including data section)

CESIL was taught in UK schools until the mid-1980s (I may have been in one of the last years that had it as an introduction before moving on to the powerhouse of BASIC).

This has been run through a parser I wrote in Python as a little exercise, each column is tab separated.

Everything has to be moved in and out of the accumulator for any function to be performed on that.

There was no real input, as it was designed for punched cards, so data has to be in a separate section at the end (I use -1 and 1 to indicate both temperature controls, and zero to terminate). It gave the correct results from the samples, but did mean I had to update the data section each time, save it, and run it again.

```
        LOAD    0
        STORE   HEAT
LOOP    IN
        JIZERO  END
        STORE   BUTTON
        ADD     HEAT
        STORE   TMP
* CHECK ZERO DOWN TO 4
        JINEG   ZTF
* CHECK 9 UP TO 0
        LOAD    TMP
        SUBTRACT        10
        JIZERO  NTZ
* CHECK 0 UP TO 9
        LOAD    BUTTON
        JINEG   DEC
        LOAD    TMP
        SUBTRACT        1
        JIZERO  ZTN
        LOAD    TMP
        STORE   HEAT

SHOW    LOAD    HEAT
        PRINT   "HEAT IS "
        OUT
        LINE
        JUMP    LOOP

DEC     LOAD    TMP
        STORE   HEAT
        JUMP    SHOW

END     HALT

* 0 GOES DOWN TO 4
ZTF     LOAD    4
        STORE   HEAT
        JUMP    SHOW

* 9 GOES UP TO 0
NTZ     LOAD    0
        STORE   HEAT
        JUMP    SHOW

* ZERO GOES UP TO 9
ZTN     LOAD    9
        STORE   HEAT
        JUMP    SHOW

        %
        -1
        -1
        -1
        1
        0
```

Comment: Never heard about CESIL before. I love the idea of teaching a low-level language to pupils. In France, my generation went through the "Plan Informatique pour Tous" which was primarily focused on Logo (aka Turtle). Better than nothing, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
 m?Z=Z%?dhZtZT=Z?d9 4QZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XyHXPso2StU@JSOqJCrENso@xVLBJDDq//9oAx0FCDKMBQA)

```
 m?Z=Z%?dhZtZT=Z?d9 4QZ   Q auto-initialized to input; Z auto-initialized to zero
 m                   Q    Map through input, using 'd' as current element
  ?Z                      If Z is not 0:   
    =Z%?dhZtZT                          Z++ or Z--, Then modulo by 10
                          Else:
              =Z?d9 4          Z = 9 if + or 4 if -
                     Z    Print Z
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 86 bytes

```
def f(c,t=0):
 if len(c):p=c[0];t=((0,9,4)[p],t+p)[t>0]%10;return f(c[1:],t)
 return t
```

Takes input as a list of 1s and -1s, 1 indicating a + button press and -1 indicating a - button press.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBqsIwELznK5bCgyymkKIXK/XyfuHdYhCpCQY0hnR7eF9fU6tYo3vJ7szO7LIJ/3S6@uUwHI0Fy1tBjcSagbNwNp63WIemVVJvqOFcirVYoQpa0CKgoq3UP5XcREN99KNaVXXikMEDooFMR3vnQ08dNKAYpFBaTG9ZPbPqBQko36pXz5yZE5Mm15V5y6dzbp4NyKd/LPB1h297TE5MM3uNwJ2A8SwIzoPx/cXEAxk@u9T4ASlCdJ548ZcI@D10BgpYQEeRO0xJUe/8jp6QvesRcbgB)

Recursively handles the exceptions that happen in what might be considered the expected function of the buttons, each at t==0.

Comment: Nice answer! Could you add a [TIO](https://tio.run/#python3) link so that others can test your code online?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added it in now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 68 bytes

Nice little lookup table solution.

Thanks to Jay Ryan for -7 bytes, and for making me revisit my code to find and fix a bug! 8 definitely is not 0, much to my previous solutions disbelief.

```python
lambda s,a=0:[[a:=b'49021324354657687980'[c+2*a]-48for c in s],a][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDLjsMgDEX3fAU7whiqvB9IfAnNgnYUTaQ2RcAi/XoGp@nG19c@WFe4d/x7bc3ofFr0NT3s8/ZraRBWl8oYq/SNtVNZV03dNl3bd0M/DtNYMnOH@sfOsh2Xl6d3um40zMLOppoTidrsl@AeayyYYpwisiPCGKOKlkTm2hLIdSISTUMkuo4AupEAfLhjWWeF44UEeSr6PtPoh6yfW3DuAb63D6DCBidNDvANdt0YnwnBbEF4TBcVoc6vWyyCWIqndcX5HbvatWbARLiE6FdXcM6F5yn9Aw)

Comment: You could save 7 bytes by taking in a binary list, right? (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>23</s></sup> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç∞/▌Çklº<&CV@‼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80ec2fdd806b6ca73c2643564013&i=%5B%5D%0A%5B-1%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B-1,-1%5D%0A%5B-1,1%5D%0A%5B1,-1%5D%0A%5B1,1%5D%0A%5B-1,-1,-1%5D%0A%5B-1,-1,1%5D%0A%5B-1,1,-1%5D%0A%5B-1,1,1%5D%0A%5B1,-1,-1%5D%0A%5B1,-1,1%5D%0A%5B1,1,-1%5D%0A%5B1,1,1%5D%0A%5B-1,-1,-1,-1%5D%0A%5B-1,-1,-1,1%5D&m=2)

Input as a list of 1s and -1s.

-9 bytes from Kevin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
¹o8 5<?+%⁵µƒ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QznwLBVMbe23VR41bD209Nsng/8PdW2wfNczV1dU63P6oaU3k//9culzaXLq6XLraXNpAJogN5AB5utogQZAoUBgkC5YGy4MU6GoDAA)

-1 thanks to xigoi: -1 is always smaller than the accumulator, and the right argument to `o` doesn't matter if it's nonzero anyways

Takes input as 1/-1.

```
           ƒ     Reduce from
            0    zero
          µ      :
¹                (break the leading triple dyad pattern.)
 o               Logical OR the left argument with
  8              eight
     <?          if it is less than the right argument,
    5            else five.
       +         Add the right argument to the result,
        %⁵       mod 10.
```

Comment: -1 byte: `R}` -> `<`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 47 bytes

```julia
l->(n=0;[n=n>0 ? (n+2i-1)%10 : 4+5i for i=l];n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9BjsIwDLz7FVakFY1MpAa2yy4ocOYNpYcVS6WgyItokPh9sQMcmkOcGU/G4/MtxV9/H/swJretONSblgNva9xhxbSIztsPX@MaP6mJ2P9fMYbUbdiO@TTkAQMaY0D6NThVAcn9A07BEpyiBkjRNxA9daW5kErlhyP3qoq/RK14JfXpRa8@0du7CLw@qIzRCAAaTkNhZBwuKeaqRJybAxvb@vWJ/5zvAOVcrpFz4iKwhUmyyZ5zewxhRrOy6HFqNDcyS426qUeyE9gLMWUsyOTxAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 111 bytes

```
	X =0
N	I =INPUT	:F(O)S($I)
A	X =REMDR(X + 1,10)
	X =EQ(X,1) 9	:(N)
S	X =X - 1
	X =4	LT(X)	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNCwdaAy4/TU8HW0y8gNITTyk3DXzNYQ8VTk8sRJBnk6usSpBGhoK1gqGNooMkFEnMN1IjQMdRUsOS00vDT5AoGiUUo6CoYgmVNOH1CNCI0IXL@nP6hIUBzgQq4XP1c/v93BAA)

Uses `A` for `+` and `S` for `-`, separated by newlines.

```
	X =0				;* Set X
N	I =INPUT	:F(O)S($I)	;* read input. If empty, goto O, else goto label identified by I
A	X =REMDR(X + 1,10)		;* Incremenet X, mod 10
	X =EQ(X,1) 9	:(N)		;* if X = 1, set it to 9. Goto N
S	X =X - 1			;* decrement X.
	X =4	LT(X)	:(N)		;* If X is less than 0, set X to 4. Goto N.
O	OUTPUT =X			;* Output X and exit.
END
```

SNOBOL won't reassign values on a FAILURE, so `X =EQ(X,1) 9` is a no-op if X isn't equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 42 bytes

```java
a->a.reduce(0,(t,c)->t<1?9>>c:(c*8-~t)%10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZAxb8MgEIX3/IpTJCtQG5RsrRM7ylKpQ6d0qzpQbLekBiw4R4qq9K9TjNyhagfE3fvgPY6TOAt2aj6C0oN1CKfY8xFVz2@2iz9aNxqJypp/oUfXCj0h2Qvv4VEoA58LgGF87ZUEjwLjdraqAR0ZOaJT5u35BbD16Gk6C/BkHwzez0G7WB@Tbw0dVEGwWnDXNqNsybogWEjKatxt9nd1LUsib27ZF9Jss6Zhm9w664CchUsZ5e8kAGUwxkurtTCNhypxLt@F84RyLQYigdUgoapgxVawhw2UsKYc7cE5cSF0OzsdLx5bze2IfIhTYUeWmS8hazKzLJJtAR0Xw9BfDj4ORdJ9P38a@XkCpbPjdTGtawiBhTwwFlge8lhOdWxix/JJnNQoTzThxKcDLP8G)

Another port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218367/16236).

The input is an `IntStream` with `-` being represented by `1` and `+` being represented by `0`.

### Credits

- -1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 30 bytes

```
0l1=?n:?v~49{?$~!
+1-a%00.>{2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDH0NY@z8q@rM7EstpepU6RS9tQN1HVwEDPrtpI6////7plCgYA) (or [fishlanguage.com](https://fishlanguage.com/), as this input format is a bit tricky)

Takes an array of `0`s(decrement) and `1`s(increment)

```
---row 1---
0               !    Initialisation
 l1=?n:              Termination
       ?             Branching to special case 0
         ~49{?$~       0 branch, discard 4 or 9 depending on button
---row 2---
+1-a%   >{2*           other branch, conditional increment/decrement mod 10
     00.               loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) 7, <strike>50</strike> 44 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$x=$_ ?$x ?++$x%10:9:$x ?$x-1:4};+$x
```

TIO still runs on PS 6, which this solution is incompatible with, so no Try It Online link, for now.

## Explanation

```powershell
$args|%{                            #For each number in the argument list (0 or 1)
    $x=                             #Assign to x
        $_                            #Ternary on the number
            ?                           #Number is non-zero, + button was pressed
                $x                        #Ternary on x
                    ? ++$x%10               #x is non-zero, set x to its increment mod 10
                    : 9                     #x is 0, set x to 9
            :                           #Number is zero, - button was pressed
                $x                        #Ternary on x
                    ? $x-1                  #x is non-zero, decrement
                    : 4                     #x is zero, set x to 4
}                                   #End for each loop
+$x                                 #Output x, coercing it to 0 if null
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>58</s> 54 bytes

-4 bytes thanks @Zaelin Goodman

```powershell
$args-ge0|%{$x=(($x-1),4,(($x+1)%10),9)[2*$_+!$x]}
+$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1fa4MwFMXf8ynu4DpMjWBa90eKIPQDbKyPpZTOpi1DZ2eUCdbP7tKYVOeD957zuyfnUvyKUp5FlvV4jNse9@VJ@icRXJ0Wm9h1sfE5ZSG7bR6nDg8oi@hmPsOd94DNtiMeNn1HSOISwtyAql/IQM@IAb/NhdLGetKrdl/VNG6gV@3Oh1sDQqv4qGzo2SrNXgYwaf6X42Muskozfu8zeDEx1AWhcAUHWgLqQ9FcRFqJAwNMizzffx8kxIC7gZZC1lmljEc8QmIPNNu8r1e1rIr87fNLvbBNWljXaSqkzpugL37GiiV82OcMX8Jq0nnv70jX/wE)

Any version of PowerShell. See also the [solution for PS7+](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218484/80745)

Comment: [54 bytes? :)](https://tio.run/##VY1fa4MwFMXf8ynu4DpMjWBa90eKIPQDbKyPpZTOpi1DZ2eUCdbP7tKYVOeD957zuyfnUvyKUp5FlvV4jNse9@VJ@icRXJ0Wm9h1sfE5ZSG7bR6nDg8oi@hmPsOd94DNtiMeNn1HSOISwtyAql/IQM@IAb/NhdLGetKrdl/VNG6gV@3Oh1sDQqv4qGzo2SrNXgYwaf6X42Muskozfu8zeDEx1AWhcAUHWgLqQ9FcRFqJAwNMizzffx8kxIC7gZZC1lmljEc8QmIPNNu8r1e1rIr87fNLvbBNWljXaSqkzpugL37GiiV82OcMX8Jq0nnv70jX/wE "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: awesome! thanks! ٩(^‿^)۶

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 21 bytes

```
:&|@>#.
-1_4^
+1_9^%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3UqtxsFPW49I1jDeJ49I2jLeMU038/z/aUEcBggzAyDAWAA)

Input as a list of `0`s and `1`s (or any other format with some character after the last number).

### Explanation

```
:&|@>#.
:        Create a copy of the temperature counter (which starts at 0).
 &       Get the next input number.
  |      Is it 0 (minus) or 1 (plus)?
         If the input is 0, move down to the second line.
         If the input is nonzero, move up (and wrap around) to the third line.

    >    Once the program has returned to the first line:
     #   Skip the next instruction.
      .  (skipped)
         Repeat.

On EOF:
:        Duplicate the final temperature.
      .  Print it.
     #   Skip the next instruction.
    >    (skipped)
   @     End the program.
    
  
Second line (minus):
-1_4^
  _      Is the copy of the current temperature zero?
         If so, 
   4            replace it with 4, 
    ^                              and return to the first line.
         If not, 
-                subtract 
 1                        1, 
    ^                        and return to the first line.


Third line (plus):
+1_9^%a
  _      Is the copy of the current temperature zero?
         If so, 
   9            replace it with 9, 
    ^                              and return to the first line.
         Otherwise, 
+                   add 
 1                      1, 
     %   take the result modulo 
      a                         10, 
    ^                               and return to the first line.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 152 bytes

```
2x0v2x3v1a2x1v1a2x2v7a2x4v1x0f3v1o0x1x1f3v3x0v2e1s2x3v6f0x1x2f4a2x3v6f0x1x3f3v3x0v4e3x4v5e1a2x3v6f0x1x4f9a2x3v6f0x1x5f9s2x3v6f0x1x6f1r3x0v0e3x1v1e3f0x6f
```

Expects a null-terminated string of SOH and STX characters (U+0001 and U+0002), representing the minus and plus buttons respectively. Variable 3 stores the temperature.

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2x0v2x3v                   # Set both variables 0 and 3 equal to 0
1a2x1v                     # Set variable 1 equal to 1
1a2x2v                     # Set variable 2 equal to 2
7a2x4v                     # Set variable 4 equal to 9
1x0f                       # Function 0
    3v1o                   # Output variable 3
1x1f                       # Function 1
    3v                     # Move variable 3 into the register
      3x0v2e               # Goto function 2 if it equals variable 0
            1s2x3v6f       # Otherwise, subtract 1, write to variable 3, & call function 6
1x2f                       # Function 2
    4a2x3v6f               # Add 4, write to variable 3, and call function 6
1x3f                       # Function 3
    3v                     # Move variable 3 into the register
      3x0v4e               # Goto function 4 if it equals variable 0
            3x4v5e         # Goto function 5 if it equals variable 4
                  1a2x3v6f # Otherwise, add 1, write to variable 3, and call function 6
1x4f                       # Function 4
    9a2x3v6f               # Add 9, write to variable 3, and call function 6
1x5f                       # Function 5
    9s2x3v6f               # Subtract 9, write to variable 3, and call function 6
1x6f                       # Function 6
    1r                     # Read a byte of input
      3x0v0e               # Goto function 0 if it equals variable 0 (NUL)
            3x1v1e         # Goto function 1 if it equals variable 1 (SOH)
                  3f       # Otherwise, call function 3
6f                         # Call function 6
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
Fold[+##/.-1->4/. 10|1/;#2>0->9-#&,0,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCoMwEIZ3n6LkQFqT00S6lNIgFDoXOkqHYBWFaiHNZvXV05DE5e6/@79vVKZvR2WGRtnuYm@f96umAEWOAuWxyHeC/0RxhlJylCeElHEGz9Te9TCZGlB2lTurbO@UmVCCUjCCbqFY0kOVXXulVWNa/V0fjZrWOSGEJY5wg/rkI/pMwzv@QxEapBGLXACjtWmbF0XXJov9Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 44 bytes

```
reduce.[]as$n(0;(7?+(.>0//2.5*$n)//$n+.)%10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oNaU0OVUvOjaxWCVPw8Baw9xeW0PPzkBf30jPVEslT1NfXyVPW09T1dBA8///6FiuaF1DIGEIZugo6MIYYEEoH8qFyCOp0UWSQNGLpB1hBJKpyAajm41mPkQXAA)

with `1` for `+` and `-1` for `-`

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
0ê{∙85ß§⌐_¬┌*ßΣ♂%
```

Uses `-1`/`1` for `-`/`+` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/g8KrqRx0zLUwPzz@0/FHPhPhDax5N6dE6PP/c4kczm1T//@fSNeQyBBI6umASyAGxQAywGFRYFyoAVwZVCFEL1QfTiaQXoR2kBgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
0                  # Start with a 0 (let's call this `r`)
                   #  STACK: 0
 ê                 # Push all inputs as integer-array
                   #  STACK: 0,[input-list]
  {                # Foreach over them (let's call these `n`):
                   #   STACK: r,n
   ∙               #  Triplicate the current integer
                   #   STACK: r,n,n,n
    85ß            #  Wrap it in a triplet-list with 8 and 5
                   #   STACK: r,n,n,[n,8,5]
       §           #  Use `n` to index into this list (0-based modulair, so 1→8; -1→5)
                   #  (let's call this `i`)
                   #   STACK: r,n,i
        ⌐          #  Rotate the stack
                   #   STACK: n,i,r
         _         #  Duplicate the top
                   #   STACK: n,i,r,r
          ¬        #  Rotate the stack back
                   #   STACK: r,n,i,r
           ┌       #  Check if the top is equal to 0
                   #   STACK: r,n,i,r==0
            *      #  Multiply the top two
                   #   STACK: r,i,n*(r==0)
             ß     #  Wrap the top three values into a list
                   #   STACK: [r,i,n*(r==0)]
              Σ    #  Sum them together
                   #   STACK: r+i+n*(r==0)
               ♂%  #  Modulo-10
                   #   STACK: (r+i+n*(r==0))%10
                   # (afterwards, the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
≔⁰θＦＳ≔⎇⁼ι+﹪⊕∨θ⁸χ⊖∨θ⁵θＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xCgIxEER7v2K5apfLwVkIwlWiFhaioD8QcvE8iInZJIJfHxOxcorXvBlG3SUrJ03OmxDmyWIvwNOwuDkGPNhnipfIs52QCH6Nq2Yr@Y17n6QJOAto2oYEHN2YjCsjxfqhbdQjnhi9gDUVu@wLdvrfrajK@nguNxG3MkT0REPOXU37Ze5e5gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start with heat setting 0.

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop through the input string.

```
≔⎇⁼ι+﹪⊕∨θ⁸χ⊖∨θ⁵θ
```

If the next character is a plus, then take the heat setting, or 8 if it was zero, and increment it modulo 10, otherwise take the heat setting, or 5 if it was zero, and decrement it.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output the final heat setting.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of [@Arnauld's Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218367/91267) to Japt.

Expects input to be a binary array where `0` represents increment and `1` represents decrement

```
£T=T°?X?T-2:T%A:9ÁXÃT
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o1Q9VLA/WD9ULTI6VCVBOjnBWMNU&input=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDFd)

### Explanation

```
£              // Map input with func (X) {
 T=            //   update T:
   T°?         //     if T is not 0 (increment T afterwards)
      X?       //       if X is 1 ('-' case)
        T-2    //          subtract 2
      :        //       else      ('+' case)
        T%A    //          modulo 10
   :           //     else
     9ÁX       //       yield 4 if X is 1 ('-' case), or 9 if X is 0 ('+' case) 
ÃT             // End map; implicit output T
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>49</s> <s>46</s> 41 bytes

```perl6
{reduce {($^u%7-2,$^t+$u)[?$t]%10},0,|$_}
```

Takes input as a list where `1` represents `+` and `-1` represents `-`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvBDoIgGADgczzFL/ttMMBJhzq0xoO0dGp4ymUgB0c8O9k6df22b7bucczTCvsRLjk6ew@DhciwCeVJHSQ2i8DArwaXW6nrJGv5xjZlH3qYO@ctQ88hkh36anhOfTV1M9t6C/YFVFAOxoCGogClEz@TRIjvVhjZL1MhFOWb/6FSSnw1fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```lisp
(λ(a)(foldl(λ(x r)(match(list x r)['(1 0)9]['(1 9)0]['(-1 0)4][_(+ r x)]))0 a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5BCoMwELz7ioEe3KUICr34FpES1LTS1ErMQd/WP/RLaRJ6aIx7mtnZmR0tusdg7EmJ6QYdSEb9IMdpgLT0eZNgki/VK49XaKanMN2d1LgYeN7kVKHkug2g5tKDwq8ubXOlMzRWbplLCGbLLn1cZiW2zAXNkMiJOMNvnPGPVJGAYsej01iNxeBN7EVydPAiebL/k/RImxx2OaoTstzAfgE)

Just simple but verbose pattern matching:

```lisp
(define (f a)
  (foldl (λ (x r)
            (match (list x r)
                 ['( 1 0) 9]
                 ['( 1 9) 0]
                 ['(-1 0) 4]
                 [_ (+ r x)]))
         0
         a))
```