# Build the stove controller (physically)

Tags: atomic-code-golf, logic-gates

### Challenge

Build the [Wheat Wizard's stove](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/218360/78410) using 2-input NAND gates. The solution with the fewest NAND gates wins.

Externally, it works in the following way: (the first line is added from the original spec for physical output)

- It has 10 levels, from 0 to 9. The display has 9 lights, and if the current level is L, exactly L lights from the left are on and the rest are off.
- Two buttons, labeled `+` and `-`, are used to control the temperature level.
- Pressing `+` changes the level as follows:

  - 0 becomes 9
  - 9 becomes 0
  - any other number is incremented
- Pressing `-` changes the level as follows:

  - 0 becomes 4
  - any other number is decremented

In summary, the circuit must behave as a [sequential circuit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/sequential_circuits.htm) with two inputs (the buttons) and 9 outputs (the lights).

### Conditions

- You can use a clock signal generator if you want, at no cost in score.
- You don't need to make the power-up behavior correct.
- You will need at least a few [latches or flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) in your circuit, in order to keep track of the current temperature level. Different latches/flip-flops cost different number of NAND gates, which is included in your score. It is your job to choose the flip-flop that gives the fewest NAND gates overall.
- One button press must affect the level exactly once, but you can choose exactly when the level changes according to input, e.g.

  - when the button is pressed
  - when the button is released
  - at the first clock tick (you can choose rising or falling edge) while the button is pressed (that button is disabled until release) - you can assume the clock cycle is short enough for this to register
- You may assume both buttons won't be pressed simultaneously.

Comment: I feel like this could use a clearer description of the available elements, how they are combined and how they interact.

Comment: @GrainGhost The available elements are a bunch of 2-input NAND gates, plus a single optional clock generator and the necessary I/O devices (2 buttons and 9 lights) as given in the spec. You're supposed to build everything else using NAND gates only, including the memory, memory update logic, and output logic.

Comment: What I mean is that because this is an abstract system you should actually explain how it works.  What real world considerations carry over?  e.g. Are wires instantaneous?  Can you split a wire indefinitely or are we going to have to worry about effects this has on current?  What happens when we wire nand gates in non-consistent ways?  Explaining the system concretely would answer these and many more questions.

Comment: Can we connect two wires to make a 0-NAND OR gate?

Answer (score 10):

## [CircuitVerse](https://circuitverse.org/), 455 NANDs

- 1x NOT (1 NANDs)
- 2x AND (4 NANDs)
- 3x OR (9 NANDs)
- 1x 4-bit 2x4 multiplexer (96 NANDs)
- 1x 4x1 Decoder (6 NANDs)
- 1x 4-bit adder (108 NANDs)
- 1x 2-bit Memory (54 NANDS)
- 1x 4-bit Memory (108 NANDs)
- 1x (4-bit) Is 1 (9 NANDs)
- 1x (4-bit) Is 10 (8 NANDs)
- 1x (4-bit) Is neg (2 NANDs)
- 1x 1-9 encoder (50 NANDs)

Total = 455

[Try it out online! (version 1.1)](https://circuitverse.org/users/102409/projects/wheat-wizard-stove-a87bea05-b156-4ddc-91da-60e961837d97)

[version 1.0 (NANDs 543)](https://circuitverse.org/users/102409/projects/wheat-wizard-stove)

Comment: Wow, TIL there's a platform where you can share live circuit schematics, with buttons and lightbulbs (diodes?) :) Currently this mostly works as expected, except for the output method - the challenge says 9 lightbulbs instead of 10, and "if the current level is L, exactly L lights from the left are on and the rest are off", not "the L-th light is on and the rest are off".

Comment: Oh, I might make a copy of the circuit (as to not change the solution posted) and fix that then. thanks for letting me know! I thought of a way to take off some more NAND gates as well so I'll do both at once :)

Comment: Also, for anybody thinking about using the circuitverse website, know that it crashes a lot! Save often, very often! Expect to lose progress if you're not saving every couple of minutes.

Comment: On page 3 of [this pdf](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/courses/dig2/5_Adder.pdf) is a full adder with just 9 NANDs, that should help with the expensive 4-bit adders

Comment: @ovs In the PDF, it uses NAND gates which have more than 2 inputs. In the challenge problem, it mentions that you are only allowed to use 2-input NAND gates. I appreciate the PDF though.

Comment: Aah, sorry for that, I should have looked a little closer. But I found another one with actual 2-input NANDs and built that one up [on Circuitverse](https://circuitverse.org/users/104639/projects/1-bit-adder-38a35425-6df2-4a77-b5b5-ecf1c4309379)